Renaming folder doesn't change name in path
(Windows 11) For installing ffmpeg I needed to rename a folder in accordance with a path in system variables. The folder was first names 'ffmpeg-7.0.2-full_build', I changed it to 'FFmpeg'. However I didn't fully change it apparantly, as I still couldn't run ffmpeg via my terminal. When I selected the path of the folder, it still contained the old name 'ffmpeg-7.0.2-full_build'. I think I understand the problem now, but I don't know how I can overcome this problem except by making a new seperate folder and then copying the contents from one folder to the next. For clarification: on my screen the folder name says 'FFmpeg', but when I select the path it says 'C:\ffmpeg-7.0.2-full_build'.
I tried renaming the folder by right-clicking and selecting naam wijzigen (Dutch for change name). I expected this would change the name, but the path of the folder still contains the old name. As for running ffmpeg, I fixed it by manually creating a new folder namer 'FFmpeg' and transfering the contents from the old to the new folder, but this seems unnecesary cumbersome.
